# Icon in JButton

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton

I am trying to add in an icon to my JButton and so far nothing has worked. I have pasted below my code for the button and also the location of where the image is stored.

```
  public static DRTextCode BUTTON_COLLAPSE_NESTED() {
    DRTextCode tc = new DRTextCode ("BUTTON_COLLAPSE_NESTED",         "Collapse");
    return tc;
}


    btn = new JButton(BUTTON_COLLAPSE_NESTED().toString());
    btn.setActionCommand(BUTTON_COLLAPSE_NESTED().toString());
    btn.addActionListener(btnListener);
    btnPnl.add(btn);
    _collapseBtn = btn;
```

This below is the images location

"mz/images/svg/folder_collapse.svg"

I am not sure how to add this in

Comment: Oh, Java doesn't support SVG out of the box

Comment: what should i do to call this image ? does it need to be a .jpg or is there another way to add in this image

Comment: Jpg, Png, bmp, gif; [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("mz/images/svg/folder_collapse.svg"));

Comment: i have added this in, will convert the image to a supported format and will update if this solution works, thanks

Comment: *"will convert the image to a supported format"* Of the formats mentioned by @MadProgrammer, only JPG, PNG & GIF are *guaranteed* to be supported. I prefer PNG or GIF for icons. Note that when loading images that `ImageIcon` will typically fail silently. Use `ImageIO.read(..)` for better feedback if there is a problem (e.g. 'missing image' or 'unsupported format'). Actually just read the linked page and found I was wrong about BMP, but it's an inefficient format that offers no advantage over the other 3 (IMO).

Comment: btn = new JButton(BUTTON_COLLAPSE_NESTED().toString());
        btn.setActionCommand(BUTTON_COLLAPSE_NESTED().toString());

  btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("mz/images/run.png"));

  btn.addActionListener(btnListener);
  btnPnl.add(btn);
  _collapseBtn = btn;

Comment: i tried the above, with a PNG Image, but no luck. The icon does not show on the button, not sure where i m going wrong

Comment: Based on your code example, the image must be stored in the "mz/images" directory relative to the execution location of your program. Try using ImageIO.read instead

Answer (score 0):

try to use .png icons because they are more common and easy to find them free,
 you can find free flat icons [here](http://www.flaticon.com/) .

- first create a folder in this path `src/resources`

[image]

- put your icons that path and use them in this way

  ```
  JButton button = new JButton();
  try {
       Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("src//resources//icon.png"));
       button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
  }
  ```

also watch these useful tutorials

- [tutorial_1](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddingIcontoJButton.htm)
- [tutorial_2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_jbutton.htm)

Comment: I have managed to get it working by adding in this line of code     btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/documentation/en/desktop/screen/collapse.png"));

Comment: Now I have another issue, this path is the exact path on my machine, but lets say that on a client machine the first part of the path until screen is different. How can I make it use the path from the word screen onwards ?

Comment: ("this path will be different/screen/collapse.png"));